# How to use the row number of a named cell in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet in which I want to use a button to add rows. I have multiple buttons on multiple rows which should each add a row at their location.

The problem is, that whenever a new row is added, the location at which I want to add a row changes. I have therefore named cells where I want to add new rows for each button.

I am having trouble getting the row number of a cell so I can choose where the new row is added. Atm I have tried this:

```
Sub Button2_Click()

Dim RowNum As Variant

Set RowNum = WorksheetFunction.Index(cell, 1, 0)
Rows(RowNum & ":" & RowNum).Insert Shift:=xlDown
Rows(RowNum - 1 & ":" & RowNum - 1).Copy Range("A" & RowNum)
Range("D" & 7, "L" & 7).ClearContents

End Sub
```

Where cell is a cell where I want to add a new row.

Im having trouble using the index function to return the row as a number. When I hover over "cell" in debug it says cell=empty.

Hope this is clear, as you can maybe tell Im not very experienced with this stuff.

Thanks :)

Comment: a) Is `cell` a named range on the worksheet? Does it have workbook or worksheet scope? b) If `cell` is A3 and contains the value 12, do you want to insert a new row at row 3 or row 12?

Comment: `cell` is a named range, it has worksheet scope (I think) but everything is in one worksheet. If `cell` is A3 I would like a row inserted at row 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Set` to assign the variant to the returned `Application.Index`, you are actually setting a range. You can simplify this to simply return the row number of the cell but you have to refer to the named range as if it were a cell address in a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx).

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim RowNum As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        RowNum = .Range("cell").Row
        .Rows(RowNum).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        .Rows(RowNum - 1).Copy .Range("A" & RowNum)
        .Range("D" & 7, "L" & 7).ClearContents   'not really sure where the 7 comes in here
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot that worked. The 7 was just a test which I haven't chancged back yet

Answer (score 0):

Try this to find the cell you named:

```
rowToInsertIn=Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("MyCellName", Range("A:A"), 0)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works but I would prefer to referece a named cell and leave the content of the cell empty. I hope this is clear